# Datatable empty or not by alert

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, datatables

Since I'm working with Datatable V. 1.10.12 and the data is rendered perfectly by PHP/Ajax/JSON I also decided to add some buttons lately. Now, I've got another delete button on top outside the table to remove the selected table row. Works fine so far. Unfortunately I encountered a little issue for when table is empty. Then it shows: NO data available in table. That's the common output for that. 
What I have in mind to do is to put on an alert message by clicking the delete button and table is empty e.g. if table empty alert('msg') and stop. NOt sure what would be the right object to check it. How can I establish it?

[image: mytable]

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      "use strict";
      var newstable = $('#tablenews').DataTable({
        responsive: true,
        //  "paging":     true,
        //  "pagingType": "full_numbers",
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": {
          url: "../pages/newsdatagrid.php", // json datasource
          type: "POST"
        },

      });

      // Simple delete button to remove selected table row
      $('#delbtn').click(function() {

        if ($('tr.selected').hasClass('selected')) {
          var id = $('.delbtn').attr('data-id');
          var data = 'id=' + id;

          if (newstable === 0) {
            alert('NO data available');
          }

          // alert(id);

          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "delrow.php",
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            success: function(response) {

              newstable.row('.selected').remove().draw(false);

              // alert(response);

            }
          });

        } else {
          alert('First select table row');
        }
      });
    });
```

Comment: btw, I've noticed that by erasing the selected table row the wrong row is removed because somehow the selected ID + 1 is counted.  How come? Same code as shown above

Answer (score 0):

define global variable and check its content after click on button :

```
var globalData;
 $('#tablenews').DataTable({
        responsive: true,
    //  "paging":     true,
    //  "pagingType": "full_numbers",
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "../pages/newsdatagrid.php",
        "fnServerData": function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
         $.ajax({
            url: sSource,
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
               globalData=data; 
               fnCallback(data);
            }
        });
    }

    });
```

for checking use this:

```
if ( globalData.length == 0) {
         alert('NO data available');
}
```

Comment: seems you are using outdatated methods here. It doesn't work for my Datatable. As a result it says: Processing... No table is ever being loaded. Somehow it's stuck. Again, I'm using V.1.10.12. Not sure, but all those fn.xxxxxx methods are useless for my Datatable. How else can I solve this?

Comment: by clicking that emtpy table row (no data available in table) it returns 'undefined'.  I tried  if ( 'undefined' != typeof id ) { alert('whatever') } but nothing.